# Prove that exists such $x_{0}$ that $f'(x_{0}) < 1 + f^{2}(x_{0})$.

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined and differentiable on a segment $[a,b]$, $b-a \ge 4$. Prove that there is a point $x_{0} \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_{0}) \lt 1 + f^{2}(x_{0})$.

I understand that if the function is decreasing, have extremums or increasing, but with derivative $f'(x)\lt 1$, the said condition is true. I also proved, that it is true for linear finctions $\alpha x + \beta$ with $\alpha \gt 1$. But i have difficulty proving it for arbitrary increasing function.

Comment: What is meant by $f^2$ in this context?

Comment: Notice that the function does not even have to be monotonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider $g(x) := \arctan f(x)$ and notice its derivative is
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{1 + f^2(x)}.
$$

What does the mean value theorem tell you?

Comment: The mean value theorem tells me that there is a point $x_{0}$ such that $g'(x_{0}) = \frac{g(b) - g(a)}{b-a}$, but $g(b) - g(a) \lt \pi$ and $b-a \gt 4$, it means $g'(x_{0}) \lt 1$,which proves the relation. Thank you very much, Daniel.